# How to convert date that displays (Wed, 25 Apr 2018) to (2018-04-25) in RUBY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, rubygems

I am trying to countdown the days from start date to end date and I built a method in Ruby that will do it but I am getting a "undefined method `div'" error in the terminal. 
After playing around I found out that when I call back the start/end date in the terminal it returns the date in this format: Wed, 25 Apr 2018.
I believe thats the reason why im getting the undefined method error.
Does anyone know how to convert the date?

The code that I have is below:

```
  def event_days
    Integer(Date.new(self.end_date.to_time) - (closer_to_end_date))
  end

  def closer_to_end_date
    if Date.today >= Date.new(self.start_date)
      Date.today
    elsif Date.new(self.start_date) >= Date.today
      Date.new(self.start_date)
    end
  end
```

FYI: When I hard code the end_date/start_date as (2018-04-25) the method works perfectly.

GitHub Repo of call: https://github.com/belalkamara/CapStone/blob/phase1/app/models/activity.rb

Comment: Problem must be coming from somewhere else, the error message explicitly talks about you calling a div something, which does not appear anywhere else in this code. We need more details about the error stack and more context to help. What you're saying about the date displayed in the terminal might only be because it uses the inspect implementation of the Date class. Calling `end_date.to_s` explicitly should display the date in ISO format yyyy-mm-dd. See https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html about this

Comment: Yes if I use `end_date.to_s` it will use the format yyyy-mm-dd. But I cant use my method by using a string since its  subtracting. The end_date and start_date are date classes in the schema file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
date.strftime("%F")
```

A good resource to check out is the docs for `strftime`: https://apidock.com/ruby/Date/strftime

Comment: I tried the strftime, but still giving me an error message.

Comment: You should post your full example so we can run it and see what you want to do more clearly. How are you invoking your methods?

Comment: I will add where im calling the method in the above edit

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what it was...I removed the Date.new() calls and it worked! Thanks JP Silvashy &  Pierre-Adrien Buisson for your help.
SO it looks like this now:

```
  def event_days
    Integer(self.end_date - closer_to_end_date)
  end

  def closer_to_end_date
    if Date.today >= self.start_date
      Date.today
    elsif self.start_date >= Date.today
      self.start_date
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails you can

```
string = "Wed, 25 Apr 2018"
date = string.to_date.strftime("%F")
=> "2018-04-25"
```

In Ruby

```
require 'date'
string = "Wed, 25 Apr 2018"
DateTime.parse(string).strftime("%F")
```